# How to fix ambiguous mapping methods

Tags: jhipster, mapstruct

I'm doing an experiment with jHipster.

I have created two entities A and B backed by DTO (mapstruct).
There is a many-to-many relationship between them.
They both also have a many-to-one relationship with the user.

Up until creating the last relationship, everything works fine.
After creating the last many-to-one relationship, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- maven-processor-plugin:2.2.4:process (process) @ m2m ---
[ERROR] diagnostic: /Users/andy/jhipster-m2m/src/main/java/com/m2m/web/rest/mapper/AMapper.java:18: error: Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping property "java.lang.Long userId" to com.m2m.domain.User: com.m2m.domain.User userFromId(java.lang.Long id), com.m2m.domain.User com.m2m.web.rest.mapper.BMapper.userFromId(java.lang.Long id).
A aDTOToA(ADTO aDTO);
  ^
[ERROR] error on execute: error during compilation
```

The definitions are very straightforward:
For A:

```
{
  "relationships": [
    {
        "relationshipId": 1,
        "relationshipName": "b",
        "otherEntityName": "b",
        "relationshipType": "many-to-many",
        "otherEntityField": "id",
        "ownerSide": true
    },
    {
        "relationshipId": 2,
        "relationshipName": "user",
        "otherEntityName": "user",
        "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
        "otherEntityField": "id"
    }
],
"fields": [
    {
        "fieldId": 1,
        "fieldName": "nameA",
        "fieldType": "String"
    }
],
"changelogDate": "20150909165353",
"dto": "mapstruct",
"pagination": "no"
```

}

For B:

```
{
"relationships": [
    {
        "relationshipId": 1,
        "relationshipName": "a",
        "otherEntityName": "a",
        "relationshipType": "many-to-many",
        "ownerSide": false,
        "otherEntityRelationshipName": "b"
    },
    {
        "relationshipId": 2,
        "relationshipName": "user",
        "otherEntityName": "user",
        "relationshipType": "many-to-one",
        "otherEntityField": "id"
    }
],
"fields": [
    {
        "fieldId": 1,
        "fieldName": "nameB",
        "fieldType": "String"
    }
],
"changelogDate": "20150909165433",
"dto": "mapstruct",
"pagination": "no"
```

}

I'm really stuck on this.
Any help is very much appreciated!!

EDIT: Providing github repo that demonstrates the problem https://github.com/andyverbunt/jhipster-m2m.git

Comment: Why do you have two methods for mapping from id to user? What is their difference?

Comment: Hi Gunnar, thanks for your feedback.

AFAIK, there are no two methods to map id to user, at least not in the same object. Entity A needs to know its owner, and the same goes for B, but they are different objects.

I'll post the example on github and edit the post so a friendly helping hand can have a look at it.

Comment: did you change anything manually? if not looks like a bug in what we generate with mapstruct. when mapstruct is trying to map userID from DTO to id in User it is seeing two methods `userFromId` doing that function, one in AMapper and another in BMapper

Comment: Haven't changed anything. It looks to me that AMapper and BMapper are unrelated, so the mapping shouldn't be ambiguous.

FYI, the problem only occurs in combo with the many-to-many relationship, so that must be somehow related (no pun intented ;))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a bug as mentioned in comment above. For time being you can either remove the method from one of the mapper or rename the method in any one mapper, we will need to look into how to avoid this during generation in Jhipster

This also can be fixed by using MapStruct qualifiers (see [Selection based on Qualifiers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.0/reference/html/index.html#selection-based-on-qualifiers) in the reference documentation).

Comment: Hi Deepu, wish I had better knowledge of how mapstruct works. I tried renaming some of the methods, but I didn't have any luck so far. Would you mind doing a pull request in the repo that I made for this - when you have the time of course...

https://github.com/andyverbunt/jhipster-m2m
I need the mapping in both A and B, so I suppose renaming is the only alternative, no?

Comment: Hi Deepu,

Did some experiments...
Changing the method name doesn't change anything. In the end it's still the same signature so it's still ambiguous.

Removing a method does work. They both do exactly the same thing, so it doesn't matter which one you delete.

As per your suggestion, I will look into the section qualifiers further. It definitely sounds like a more clean solution. I hope it will make jHipster 2.21 as I am convinced a lot of people are impacted by this bug.

I think we should leave the bugreport open, no?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ya please leave it open

Comment: Hi Deepu, for what it's worth: I removed all the userFromId methods in my existing mappers. Then I created my own UserMapper that has the userFromId method and referenced it via the @Mapper annotation in each mapper. This seems to work although I'm not sure it's the best way. I do know that removing the method in more complex cases (such as the A & B entity in my example) doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug, but not like mentioned above. The JHipster mapper generator doesn't correctly add @Mapper(..., users = {UserMapper.class}) to the Mapper classes. I'm answering this a year later because this is still the case with JHipster 3.12.2.

In the source you shared replace the following line:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {BMapper.class, })
```

With this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {BMapper.class, UserMapper.class})
```